# Max of a part of split string

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have, in my DB oracle 10g, a field that contains references.

It's stored as : name/yyyy/mm/number

The new number, is the max number found in the part mm/number.

So, for now, I have a split of my string that gives me a list of str_array like this :

str_array(name, yyyy, mm, number)

I'd like, with this, found max number, for the couple mm/number.

Is this possible to do this?

Can I have something like :

```
  SELECT MAX(split(reference, '/').lastPartOfArray) into nb
        FROM table
where lastPartOfArray-1 = sysdate.month;
```

Data samples :

```
Smith/2013/12/1
Smith/2013/11/1
Smith/2013/12/3
Jones/2013/12/6
Smith/2013/12/3
Jones/2013/11/7
```

Since we are in the month 12, a max on those data must give me 6 into nb.

The number part, has no limit, it can be 1000, 10000...

The part Jones/2013 doesn't really matter for the number. But I can't have the same number, for a month.

My apologies, I don't know if this is possible, so I tried to write what I want in the query.

Is this possible, or should I create more than one field in my table(`name/yyyy`, `mm`, `number`)?

**edit : valex answer and some custom**

```
select MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(num,INSTR(num,'/')+9,1000) as Int))
from T 
where num like TO_CHAR(sysdate,'%/YYYY/MM/%')
```

So this, count searching first occurence.

```
select MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(num,INSTR(num,'/',1 ,n)+1,1000) as Int))
from T 
where num like TO_CHAR(sysdate,'%/YYYY/MM/%')
```

This found the n occurence of the char.

This is a helpful solution in other cases.

Comment: Can you post a sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Despite this most likely being possible in some way, you really should split up your values in your table. Meaning, create one column for each value!

Comment: @JorgeCampos : add some data samples.

Comment: Great. You want a max for a given month (there is already an answer) or you want maxes for months? say 12 - 6 / 11 - 7 ?

Comment: A max for a given month. But, it is always the actual month in the WHERE clause. If we were in november, nb will be 7, in december, it will be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a maximum you should convert this last part into INT values otherwise you can get not right results because of STRING comparing rules will be used. 
As soon as `/YYYY/MM/` has got a fixed length = 9 so we can find first `\` position and add 9 to this position to find a last part number substring start.

Here is an example:

```
select MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(num,INSTR(num,'/')+9,1000) as Int))
from T 
where num like TO_CHAR(sysdate,'%/YYYY/MM/%')
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79698/7)</kbd>

Also you can exclude wrong formatted values from this query to avoid conversion errors [using the following way](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php):

```
select MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(num,INSTR(num,'/')+9,1000) as Int))
from T 
where num like TO_CHAR(sysdate,'%/YYYY/MM/%')
AND 
LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(num,INSTR(num,'/')+9,1000),
                      ' 0123456789', ' '))) is null
```

<kbd>[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96d8a/1)</kbd>

Comment: This looks good. If I may, can you details some parts? `INSTR()+9` . So, tihs is working like this, but I'd like to understant this part : `INSTR()+9` Thank you.

Comment: I've added explanation to my answer.

Comment: Just to confirm : if my reference format changes, and a part of it is variable (2,3 or 4 char). This code will not work right? Here, we catch the first `/` . Can't we, catch the last one (or maybe, the occurence n), to have a query more secure?

Comment: Found a way with the INSTR documentation. Add some edit in my question, for those who will search this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(SUBSTR(num, INSTR(num, '/', 1, 3) + 1))
FROM ref
WHERE
    SUBSTR(num, INSTR(num, '/', 1, 2) + 1, INSTR(num, '/', 1, 3) - INSTR(num, '/', 1, 2) - 1) = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM')
```

Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b03a/1